# Get api param from json file java with arrays

Tags: java, json, file, vert.x

I have a json a file that doesnt contain only my api i am new to json and trying to get my api parameters from the file

```
"operators": {
    "tez" : {
      "api": "www.my-tour.com/search/getResult",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "country": "Canada",
          "queryParameters": {
            "priceMin": ["0"],
            "priceMax":["150000"],
            "currency":["5561"],
            "nightsMin":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13], 
            "nightsMax":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
```

In my app operator is just simple the company that owns the api so i have many operators so "tez" is the name of the company and below is its api and param

```
@Override
    public JsonObject fetchData(String url) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 180; i++) {
            String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(calendar);
            url += "&after=" + formattedDate + "&before=" + formattedDate;
           // how can i get the api iteratively to get all api param
            JsonObject json = new JsonObject().getJsonObject("tez");
            // TODO call eternal API here
            JSONParser  parser = new JSONParser();
            JsonObject a = null;
            try {
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("\\home\\user\\MyProjects\\MicroserviceBoilerPlate\\src\\config\\local_file.json");
                a = (JsonObject) parser.parse(fileReader);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This above is what i am came up with but its not correct im not able to access the json file and how can i iterate through the parameters so i can add them to the api 
www.my-tour.com/search/getResult?priceMin=0&priceMax=150000&currency=+value &nightsMin= + value &nightsMax=+values etc

Note: This is a vertx app and i am using JsonObject and other Json specific api's

Answer (score 1):

You could just make an object of the JSON properties in the file

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import java.util.List;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TezModel {
    public Operators operators;

    public String getApi() {
        return operators.tez.api;
    }

    public List<String> getPriceMin() {
        return operators.tez.parameters.get(0).queryParameters.priceMin;
    }

    public List<String> getPriceMax() {
        return operators.tez.parameters.get(0).queryParameters.priceMax;
    }

    public List<String> getCurrency() {
        return operators.tez.parameters.get(0).queryParameters.currency;
    }

    public List<Integer> getNightsMin() {
        return operators.tez.parameters.get(0).queryParameters.nightsMin;
    }

    public List<Integer> getNightsMax() {
        return operators.tez.parameters.get(0).queryParameters.nightsMax;
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Operators {
        public Tez tez;
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Tez {
        public String api;
        public List<Parameters> parameters;
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Parameters {
        public String country;
        public QueryParameters queryParameters;
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class QueryParameters {
        public List<String> priceMin;
        public List<String> priceMax;
        public List<String> currency;
        public List<Integer> nightsMin;
        public List<Integer> nightsMax;
    }
}
```

And then you could add your parameters to a string using jackson databind

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TezModel tezModel = mapper.readValue(new File("local_file.json"), TezModel.class);
    String api = tezModel.getApi()+ "+priceMin="
            + tezModel.getPriceMin().get(0)
            + "&priceMax=" + tezModel.getPriceMax().get(0)
            + "&currency=+" + tezModel.getCurrency().get(0)
            +  "nightsMin=" + tezModel.getNightsMin().get(0)
            + "nightsMax=" + tezModel.getNightsMax().get(0);
    System.out.println(api);
}
```

Comment: @Christopher Clausen is thisinot a bit of hard coding when u write get(0) what happens to the other values may be a for loop or something?\

Comment: Yes, get(0) only retrieves the first values. You can loop through the arrays to get the values you want. If you give me an example of the values you need, i can update the answer.